# Set up transparent GRE/VPN to redirect all traffic to an External datacenter

Tags: vpn, gre

I need to setup an existing server with multiple IPs (from OVH) to send all the traffic (through VPN or GRE tunnel) to an external server that has only 1 Public IP.

I want to make it like every local IP in the external datacenter has a OVH IP on the server.
*Example: OVH IP 1.2.3.4 redirects traffic to 192.168.1.4*

Basically, this is the situation resumed in one image:
[image: Network situation]

Problem with VPN is that incoming traffic from the internet does not maintain the original source IP, but after the NAT traslation get the IP of the OVH server.

Any ideas on what to do here?

At the moment, only the GRE tunnel is done and works.

Answer (score 0):

Your OVH box is set to NAT all outgoing traffic, including traffic over your GRE/VPN. Exclude your GRE/VPN interface from the NAT rules. Add your current nat table rules to your question for a more precise answer.

Comment: For the moment i have only the gre tunnel working, i want to know how can i do it, i'm not very familiar with iptables